# Database design for graph where nodes can be other graphs

Tags: database-design, relational-database, graph, entity

How should I design a relational schema to store graph documents that can contain plain nodes (shapes, in the example below) as well as nodes that can reference other graph documents?

To visually describe the data I'm storing, consider document A with three nodes, two of which are shapes and one is a reference to document B:

[image: Sample graph document A]

I started out by using two separate tables to store the document's node information, one containing shapes and the other containing documents. But this doesn't work well with the edges table, which can contain edges between shapes, between documents, or between a shape and a document.

```sql
create table documents (
  id uuid default uuid_generate_v4() primary key,
  created_on timestamp default now() not null,
  title character not null
);

create table shapes (
  id uuid default uuid_generate_v4() primary key,
  created_on timestamp default now(),
  name character,
  description text
);

create table document_nodes_shapes (
  document_id uuid references documents (id),
  shape_id uuid references shapes (id),
  local_name character,
  primary key(document_id, shape_id)
);

create table document_nodes_documents (
  document_id uuid references documents (id),
  other_document_id uuid references documents (id),
  local_name character,
  primary key(document_id, other_document_id)
);

/* how to accommodate this? */
create table document_edges (
  document_id uuid references documents (id),
  start_node uuid,
  end_node uuid
);
```

My RDBMS is PostgreSQL if that matters. As to why PostgreSQL was chosen rather than a graph database, there were various factors to lead to this decision. Alternatives that can be considered include MariaDB and possibly Microsoft SQL Server, though I don't think this fundamental design issue would be mitigated by switching RDBMS.

The problem with the existing structure is edges 2 and 3 are between shape nodes, whereas edges 1 and 4 are between shape and document nodes.

One solution I thought about was having one table with more columns:

```sql
create table document_nodes (
  node_id uuid default uuid_generate_v4() primary key,
  document_id uuid references documents (id),
  shape_id uuid references shapes (id),
  other_document_id uuid references documents (id),
  local_name character,
  unique key(document_id, shape_id),
  unique key(document_id, other_document_id)
)
```

And enforce a constraint which guarantees exactly one of `shape_id` or `other_document_id`.

This would solve the edges table problem by referencing `document_nodes (node_id)` for both start and end values, but the design of the document_nodes table seems iffy here.

Comment: Is it that important the referencial integrity as for you to have 1 table per different edge? I'm not an expert on the subject, but whenever I have implemented graphs or trees with multiple nodes (n-n) the constraints have been troublesome. If you can work without, you only need one edge table since all nodes (no matter the type) use uuid

Comment: Why not use a NoSQL database, which is good at storing structural data that can be represented as XML or JSON?

Comment: Even if someone said, "use a RDMS", there is nothing wrong with going back to them with an alternate solution that would work better.

Comment: @DocBrown Would you mind adding an answer to expand on that with an example? I can't seem to grasp how the OOP pattern would map to relational tables.

Comment: @Laiv For that option, I suppose there will also only be one nodes table that have a type column to determine whether the uuid is a shape or document?

Comment: Why is important for the edge to know the type of each node?

Answer (score 2):

You need a generalized entity of shapes and documents - which in this case should be called "node" - and define the edges between shapes and documents in terms of nodes, not in terms of documents and shapes. This will lead to the following table design:

- Table `Node`: contains an ID; if necessary, it can also hold type information if it represents a shape or a document. If you have more attributes common to shapes and documents, you can add them here, too.
- Tables `Shapes` and `Document`: both have a mandatory 1:1 relationship to `Node`, as well as individual attributes for shapes and documents. Their  foreign key `nodeId` is also their primary key. You can think of an OO model with `Shape` and `Document` as classes which inherit from a common base class `Node`, and then resolve that OO model to relational tables with the common "one table per class" mapping.
- Table `Edge`: has two foreign keys *fromNodeId* and *toNodeId*, so it models a directed m:n relationship between nodes. If you want some restriction here like that only shapes can contain outgoing nodes but not documents, replace *fromNodeId* by *fromShapeId*.

This approach has some similarities to the [Composite pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern), where *composite* and *leaf* both inherit from their generalization, a *component*.

Of course, it is not necessary to use 3 tables here, alternatively you can just make a `node` table which is filled with shapes and documents, and distinguish between the two by a type flag. That is the object-relational "one-table-per-class-hierarchy" mapping. The latter might be preferable when you don't expect shapes and documents to have a lot of different attributes.

Comment: I wonder if, from the `DB -to->Entity` mapping point of view, wouldn't be more efficient to work width edges instead of nodes. Pulling a graph from DB node by node can be challenging or the hell if there's an ORM doing the job. However, edges are "composed" of two nodes (up|down or start|end). It flattens the graph and the way to fetch it. I guess it depends on the depth of the graph and whether cyclic graphs are allowed or not.

Comment: @Laiv: when one needs individual attributes for edges *and* nodes (which we don't know for this case), I think it is straightforward to have both, and edge table and a node table.

Comment: I don't think that `Edge` describes a containment relation. It describes the edges (astonishingly). Containment could be modeled using a `parent` foreign key in `Node` which should always reference a `Document`.

Comment: @Hans-MartinMosner: ok, I renamed my example attributes and leave it open to whomever is using this.